# Why are we using payable modifiers in both the ERC20 transferFrom and approve functions?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, payable

Why are we using payable modifiers in the ERC20 functions below?

```
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external **payable** {
    require (zombieToOwner[_tokenId] == msg.sender || zombieApprovals[_tokenId] == msg.sender);
    _transfer(_from, _to, _tokenId);
  }

function approve(address _approved, uint256 _tokenId) external **payable** {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `payable` keyword is required for functions and addresses to be able to receive **Ether**.

By declaring it in `transferFrom()` and `approve()`, you are not only able to pay a contract with your **ERC20** token, but also with **Ether**.